# Scan files from hard drive with Android

Tags: android, usb

I want to scan list of image from Hard disk connected to Android phone via USB connection.
Device run Android version 3.1 or higher. Can I do it?

Please help!

Comment: Which android version supporting usb host functionality ? can you say which mobile you are using ?

Comment: Dear Yugandhar Babu, I'm writing a program that can scan images from hard disk. The Android version is 3.1 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are devices supporting this. Min. Req. is Android 3.1 and the Pad I know of supporting is, is the Motorola Xoom. There was an example from google in which an app was able to use the USB Rocketlauncher.

More Information can be found here:

[Android Devices as USB Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the current Android devices can act as a USB host only as a USB device when attached to a host. So using the USB port as a serial port is not likely.
I don't think that's possible with existing API's. You should have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=738).....

Recently for 3.1, there were Accessory API's released for external USB hardware (an Android USB accessory) to interact with an Android-powered device in a special "accessory" mode.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html)

or You could rebuild your kernel to support the USB host functionality, but that isn't as simple as it looks. You can google for more info.